# IIS 10 server hosted on AWS will not serve aspx

Tags: amazon-web-services

Have an app that has been running for years using on-premise and virtual systems.  It's an ASP.NET application.  Stood up a VM on AWS running server 2019 configured identical to another VM running on different provider.  The instance of IIS running on AWS VM will not serve up the site.  The non AWS server was running server 2016 so i created a new VM on AWS using server 2016.  Get the same identical problem.

If i load a dummy html page (typical hello world) the page comes up fine, so i know it's not a DNS issue or anything like that.

when I looked at the logs in IIS i see a 302 status code.  for the life of me I can't figure out why this thing won't serve up the site.  I check all the extensibility, etc.  I have configured the IIS on both systems identically.  AWS says it's an IIS issue.  How is that possible if it is configured exactly the same?

If it was an application issue wouldn't we see a 500 error?

Looking for any ideas.

thanks..  FYI this is critical at this point.  Trying to migrate a customer on AWS.

Comment: A little more info here:  if i put a bogus filename in the url e.g. thissite.com/bogus.html i get a valid 404 error.  If I leave the filename off or use the default.aspx page, then i get the time out with the 302 error.

Comment: We got it figured out.  When you use lightsail you MUST add rule for HTTPS in their networking.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that AWS has https turned off by default, so you have to add a rule to the lightsail firewall to allow https traffic to get through.  who would have thunk it?